# Check every column in a spark dataframe has a certain value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Can we check to see if every column in a spark dataframe contains a certain string(example "Y") using Spark-SQL or scala?

I have tried the following but don't think it is working properly.

```
df.select(df.col("*")).filter("'*' =='Y'")
```

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: what you have tried so far and what is result? and what was not working? seems like the question is abstract. provide code snippet of what you have tried

Comment: Hello Ram,Added the code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this to keep the rows where all columns contain 'Y':

```
//Get all columns
val columns: Array[String] = df.columns

//For each column, keep the rows with 'Y'
val seqDfs: Seq[DataFrame] = columns.map(name => df.filter(s"$name == 'Y'"))

//Union all the dataframes together into one final dataframe
val output: DataFrame = seqDfs.reduceRight(_ union _)
```

Comment: Hello Sohum. Thank you. Though it works in parts,when I try to write it to a file it repeats the same output many times.

Comment: The issue with with solution is if you have some row and two columns of this row have 'Y' value you are going to have two same rows in a result dataframe. If three columns of a row have 'Y' value you are going to have three same rows in a result dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use data frame method *columns* to get all column's names

```
val columnNames: Array[String] = df.columns
```

and then add all filters in a loop

```
var filteredDf = df.select(join5.col("*"))

for(name <- columnNames) {
    filteredDf = filteredDf.filter(s"$name =='Y'")
}
```

or you can create a SQL query using same approach

Comment: Hello Andrei,Thank you for the response.I really appreciate it.However,I would like to check if the value in every column contains "Y" and not the column name.

Comment: filter(s"$name =='Y'")
This filter checks if the value of the column with name $name equals 'Y'. If you want to check 'contains' you can use 
filter(s"$name like '%Y%' ").

Expression 
s"$name like '%Y%' 
checks the column value for specific column, not column name

Comment: thank you Andrei.Will try that and let you know.Appreciate the effort.

Comment: Hello Andrei.I tried the solution but it doesn't seem to be doing the right thing.

Comment: Can you post your code with explanation how you expect it to work?

Comment: The problem here is, that multiple filters are a concatenation of multiple AND, so you basically end up with rows, where the value in EVERY COLUMN is equal to Y

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter every row, in which any of the columns is equal to 1 (or anything else), you can dynamically create a query like this:

```
cols = [col(c) == lit(1) for c in patients.columns]
query = cols[0]

for c in cols[1:]:
    query |= c

df.filter(query).show()
```

It's a bit verbose, but it is very clear what is happening. A more elegant version would be:

```
res = df.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,  (col(c) == lit(1) for c in cols)))
res.show()
```